# MySQL (phpMyAdmin): #1045 - Access denied for user: 'root'@'localhost' (Using password: Yes)

Tags: mysql, php

I'm getting the following error:

> `#1045 - Access denied for user: 'root'@'localhost' (Using password: Yes)`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, please ensure a few things:

1. You are connecting from the localhost. Both phpmyadmin and mysql need to be running on the same server. If they are on different servers, the localhost connection will not work.
2. You have supplied the correct passwords for the *root* user.

Answer (score 1):

It really does look like you don't have the correct password for the root account but as a first step I recommend you stop using the root account. Instead, create a new account, giving it only the permissions it actually requires, and use that account for phpMyAdmin, making sure you enter the user name and password correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Cant be sure what the exact problem is with just that, you should provide more info.

So the is nothing more than general help.

The error is caused by a mistaken password for root, have you set it? are you sure
it is correct?

If the is a local system or you are the admin,
try the link and reset the password for mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/passwords.html

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem specifically with MySQL 5 and phpMyAdmin on RedHat.  If I recall, it was due to an older mysqllib on the phpMyAdmin box.  We worked around this issue by setting the MySQL passwords on users who where accessing the database through phpMyAdmin using OLD_PASSWORD() instead of PASSWORD

```
use mysql;
update USER set password=old_password('password') where user=user;
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 0):

check for a file called `config.inc.php` in phpMyAdmin folder and add the password for the database as well as the user name if u changed it